# Variable importance in regression with large number of missing values

Tags: regression, feature-selection, missing-data, multiple-imputation

I have a dataset with multiple (approximately 20) categorical and ordinal predictors and a numerical outcome and I am trying to understand which and how each of these predictors affect the outcome (explain the variance or are more correlated with it). Some of the categorical predictors have a large number of levels (e.g. can be a city or a website domain).

My problem is that each predictor has a large number of missing values (a bit more than 10-15%) but at different rows. The missing values are missing at random (are not available due to the lack of logging and are not systematically missing).

Since I am currently just exploring the dataset, I do not know which of these predictors to keep. I tried to perform some kNN imputation but it did not work because of the large number of missing values. I would like to either use a random forest and look at the variable importances or run some multiple linear regression model (possibly using a Lasso procedure), however the more predictors I add the higher is the number of missing values in the dataset that makes it more difficult to derive any conclusions.

Is there any systematic method of dealing with this problem? Being a complete novice, any references would be highly appreciated.

Comment: 10-15% is not that bad. A quick fix for RF, is to set all missing values to K, where K is larger than any other value, or some new category. Then just run RF as normal. You could also first use rfImpute and impute the values. The imputed data set would be compatible with other models.

Comment: rfImpute is from the R cran randomForest pakage...

Comment: Thank you, I will try the rfImpute. I tried a bit with randomForest but it would not run for other reasons (large number of levels in my categorical variables)

Comment: You need to alias som of your **c** categorical levels to get down to **c** =  5-15. How many samples do you have? Otherwise  randomForest implementation is too slow testing 2^(**c**-1) potential splits of categories. Try to be creative figure out how to cut down on categories in some meaningful way or use kmeans clustering and then merge categories within each variable which tend to end up in same cluster.  If not possible, swap to Rborist, extraTrees or sklearn python which in different ways ignores to many categories in their RF implementation. Anyhow to many categories limit performance.

Comment: I have a number of different datasets, each with approximately 300000-400000 records. I will try the R packages first and then see if it is worth moving to sklearn. It is too bad that R has the stats packages and Python the performance. I thought about kmeans clustering as well, great idea, will update you on the results. Please feel free to write a full answer and I will upvote it. Thank you again for your help

Comment: Btw, I can't believe that people have not come up with solutions for categorical variables such as city which often appears in datasets. Probably there is something out there but I did not manage to find it.